# JTA transaction configuration in ibm liberty

Tags: java, multithreading, transactions, websphere-liberty, jta

I have an `MDB` to trigger a process (thread) based on some conditions. The `process/thread` is a long running process so we don't want to hold the thread that triggered the `MDB`.

So we create a new Thread and submit it to the managed task executor in liberty and occasionally goes to sleep when things are not ready.

The thread reads records from DB, posts as message to another `MQ/JMS Queue` and then writes a record to DB.

I want the `MQ/JMS message` and DB write to be part of a `transaction` - both should succeed/fail together.

How do I do that in `IBM liberty environment`.

Any suggestions/help is appreciated. Thank you!!

I tried annotating with `@Transactional` with `REQUIRES_NEW`, but doesn't work.

Usually we may have to define that we use `JTA transaction's` and then annotate with `@Transactional`.

Answer (score 3):

ManagedExecutorService tasks, per spec, do not run under a transaction. However, they do have the ability to start new transactions.  You can do so as follows,

```
executor.submit(() -> {
    UserTransaction tx = InitialContext.doLookup("java:comp/UserTransaction");
    tx.begin();
    try {
        try (Connection con = dataSource.getConnection()) {
            ResultSet results = con.createStatement().executeQuery(...);
            ... process result set and send messages
            ... update database
        }
    } finally {
        tx.commit(); // or tx.rollback
    }
    return null;
});
```

Comment: thanks this seem to work, but have another problem. I encapsulated posting to jms and updating to DB into a another method and in that method, i am opening a transaction. When I throw an exception after posting to JMS queue, the result set of the code calling this method is also close. Is this not the right way of doing it?

Comment: Basically i want just posting to JMS and updating DB into one transaction. If either of this fails, i want to continue with other records in the resultset.

Comment: I think it would help for you to show more of the code you have so far, sketching out the JDBC calls in each of the "outer" method doing the DB read, and the "inner" method doing the DB update and JMS send in the transaction, as well as any exception handling.   This might even end up better posted as a new, separate question but hard to say.

Answer (score 0):

When we create our own threads, then the container's don't allow us to manage the transactions - specifically when we call commit on a JMS session.

Worked out this way : 
I invoke an asynchronous session bean from the MDB. 
The container itself manages transaction of this session bean.
Wrap up posting the message and db transactions into another session bean which manages its own transactions (@TransactionManagement(value=TransactionManagementType.BEAN)).

In the bean managed method, inject the UserTransaction object :
@Resource 
    UserTransaction userTransaction;

And then manage the transaction using : userTransaction.begin(); and userTransaction.commit(); and userTransaction.rollback();

Answer (score -1):

If you are talking about distributed system, then you can't do the JMS message be transaсtional, you'll send it anyway. You should use idempotency. And you read and write to db should be in transaсtion.

Transaction:
   - read from db
   - send JMS
   - write to db

Even if you service fails and you don't proceed your transaction, next time you will send the JMS again, but the JSM receiver service will react to this operation idempotently (just ignore it)